# Displaying an image with different name

Tags: php, apache, apache2

On my website I let users upload images.

I save the images under some hashed (based on name + timestamp) name.

I store both the original name as the hashed name in the database.

I would like to display the image on my page using the original name.

**CASE**

- user uploads `test.jpg`
- image is saved as `/img/6eabd22d35b4132cc58e4dff75e466cc1e444d93053ca80087b12ff620bd3451` on the server
- both original and hashed names are stored in database
- display the image on a page using the original name (`<img src="/img/test.jpg" alt="" title="">`) which actually is `/img/6eabd22d35b4132cc58e4dff75e466cc1e444d93053ca80087b12ff620bd3451`

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just rewrite all image requests to a script which fetches the real local name from the database & outputs the correct image.

Comment: Look up mod_rewrite (I'm assuming apache, here).

Comment: @Wrikken: Should I create an Apache RewriteRule for this, which rewrites all requests to /img/* to a php file. Which in turn return the images content?

Comment: @Wrikken: can you please post as answer. With example rewriterule would even be better, but not mandatory. If you don't I'll add it to you answer to make it complete once I've done it :)

Comment: @wrikken: and if two different users upload a `test.jpg`?

Comment: @Marc B: I blatantly assumed a unique index, PeeHaa: you do make sure those filenames are unique, don't you?

Comment: @Wrikken: yeah, because if the filenames aren't unique, OP's hosed. and if they are unique, then why bother with the hashed filename in the first place? Just store by the original filename and the whole problem is avoided.

Comment: @Marc B: I hash the combo timestamp + name. Because users can upload files with the same name

Comment: Except when you for some reason take the precaution storing all user-supplied content outside the document root giving you more control about how they're handled (for instance, I've seen _terrible_ setups that just ran _every_ file through the PHP parser, not something you'd like to do with possibly dangerous files, but the more sane reaction would be to immediately switch hosts).

Comment: peehaa: then you have no way to uniquely identify WHICH user's `test.jpg` you want to load. If 500 people upload `test.jpg`, which user's image does `<img src="/img/test.jpg" />` refer to?

Comment: @PeeHaa: forget all answers, it's not possible unless you enforce some kind of uniqueness (for instance: unique filename per user and some url like `/img/<user_id>/filename`).

Comment: Although you could of course serve the current logged in users file, but under what circumstances an application would need that kind of functionality I can't imagine right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. What I wanted to do is simply not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's definitely possible. It's actually quite easy, you have to:

- Rewrite all requests that conform to that pattern to a (PHP) script using the Apache module mod_rewrite;
- In that script fetch the real name from the database and display the image. Don't forget to also send the correct header, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I would suggest making a relational table which holds your hash to filename. When you do the query you can return an array of both results, one used for the image source, and the other used for the name.

Comment: I quote _"I store both the original name as the hashed name in the database"_

Comment: @Headspin: Uhhhhhmmmm. I state I store both the hash and the original filename.